# ActiveAdmin custom filter with HBTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, meta-search

I'd like to be able to filter an object with this associations

```
ActiveAdmin.register Vendor do
  filter :"market" , :as => :select, :collection => Market.all
end

Model Market
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vendors
Model Vendor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :associated_markets, :class_name => "Market"
```

But I recieve an error:

```
undefined method `market_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Vendor:0x007f9f5c02dd18>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  filter :associated_markets_id, collection: proc { Market.all }, as: :select
```

Comment: To expand on his answer here you need to use the attribute name of the associated model (e.g. `:associated_markets_id`) rather than the name of the model itself (`:market`).